# Is there a way to transport my choices from first game on Android to second game on Xbox One?

Tags: the-banner-saga, the-banner-saga-2

So I'm playing the first "The Banner Saga" game on Android, and I have the second game on Xbox One.

My question is: **Can I import my choices from the first game to the second game?**

Maybe there's a "Banner Saga account" that saves your choices and you can import in any platform?

Comment: Unless there is some sort of Banner Saga Account system that reaches across both platforms, I'm going to venture and say there is no way to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/237990/discussions/0/365172547937862465/) on Steam forums it's only possible between Steam/iOS and it isn't official but a fan made tool. The user, Aleonymous, is also registered in the Banner Saga forums and seems to have certain reputation or even know the developers as seen [here](http://stoicstudio.com/forum/showthread.php?3781-How-to-import-saved-games-on-iPad&highlight=import) therefore I believe that's correct as of today.

Also, as far as I know, there isn't such thing as a Stoic/Banner Saga account.